# Need to find stored Video Server password in Axis Camera Station Client Software

Tags: webcam, ip-camera

Does anyone know how where the video server password is stored within Axis Camera Station (ACS) software? I have a Windows user that auto-logs in with Admin privileges but I need to make a new Windows user that will have less-access. Unfortunately I do not know the remote video server password. The user is 'root'

Any help would be appreciated. I know this specific area isn't too popular on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you were looking for but axis camera station uses a windows user to login to axis camera station. Then axis camera station needs to know the username and password for the camera to be able to add it to the system. There is no way of getting the password for the camera if it's unknown or been forgotten, you would need to factory default the camera. The default credentials for the cameras are :
Username:root 
Passwors:pass